# htaccess: redirect 301 image if it doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

in my htaccess file I should make sure that if a resource "a specific image" is not present it must do a 301 redirect with a different extension.

I try to explain myself better:

image: `test.webp`

if it does not exist, it must postpone:

```
test.jpg
```

Can such a thing be done?
I apologize if I don't write an example of my code, but I really don't know just how to handle it in my htaccess.

Thank you

Comment: "a specific image" - so, it's literally just this one file `test.webp`, not `<anything>.webp`? Could this `.webp` image exist in the future? Presumably browser support is not a concern?

Comment: it actually could be <anything>.webp

The image webp will not exist in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "webp" images that do not exist to "jpg"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.webp$ /$1.jpg [R=301,L]
```

For any request to a `.webp` file that does not exist, a 301 redirect is triggered to the same file but with a `.jpg` extension. eg. `/foo/bar/does-not-exist.webp` is redirected to `/foo/bar/does-not-exist.jpg`.

To also check that the target `.jpg` exists (before redirecting) you can add an additional condition. For example:

```
# Check that corresponding ".jpg" file exists before redirecting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.webp$ /$1.jpg [R=301,L]
```

However, I would question whether an external 3xx redirect is really the correct thing to be using here. This can be inefficient/slow if you have many such files. eg. Trigger an internal rewrite instead? For example, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71280786/369434) to the following question:

- [webp fallback jpg using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280090/webp-fallback-jpg-using-htaccess)